# Pass values from a post to the template header tags

Tags: blogs, blogger, facebook-opengraph

Basically i want to pass an Image **url** from a post to the **open graph image** meta tag so i can choose which image to show on a facebook post.

I found this solution, but it only work if your fist image is what you want be shown, it didn't give you control.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' property='og:image'/>
<b:else/>
<meta content='[The image url]' property='og:image'/>
</b:if>
```

Thank you

Comment: open graph images should not be changed. they get cached.

Answer (score 0):

Blogger added the first image as post thumbnail. So you don't have option to show og:image as other one.